# порядок колонок в множественном индексе

Tags: база-данных, oracle, запрос, индексы

Добрый день!
Как тот или иной порядок колонок в множественном индексе влияет на производительность запрос?
Понятных и наглядных объяснений в интернете нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в условии запроса перечислены все колонки находящиеся в индексе, то скорость его работы будет примерно одинаковая не зависимо от того, в каком порядке расположены колонки в многоколоночном индексе.

Если в условии запроса могут быть перечислены не все колонки входящие в состав индекса то тут порядок колонок в индексе может сыграть роль в том, как Oracle будет использовать индекс.

Возьмем пример из другого ответа и представим, что у нас есть три колонки A, B,C и построенный по ним индекс с таким же порядком колонок, тогда Oralce ***может*** ипспользовать индекс так:

1. Если в условии указано A, B - **Index Range Scan**
2. Если в условии указано A, C - **Index Range Scan**
3. Если в условии указано B, C - **Index Full Scan** или **Index Sckip Scan**
4. Если в условии указано C - **Index Full Scan**

---

**Index Skip Scan** самый непривычный. Он может быть использован, если в услови отсутствует колонка указанная первой в многоколоночном индексе. 
Я как-то рисовал картинку показывающую примерный принцип его работы.
Представим что есть составной индекс (CHAR, NUM) и идет поиск строк с условием NUM = 2, тогда **Index Skip Scan** будет выглядеть примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это ведь логическое представление? физически, это 1 таблица с упорядоченными парами значений?

Comment: Картинка - представление двухколоночного индекса и проходу по нему. Ну а в индексе значения упорядочены. Если это не IOT, то в таблице строки распределены случайным образом.

Comment: я имел ввиду, что в памяти - это одна таблица, в которой пары упорядочены и соседствуют друг с другом

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то физически таблица не хранит значения в упорядоченных парах.

Comment: я хотел сказать не таблица, а индекс! ps пора спать

Comment: Про физическое хранение индекса я сейчас 100% точно не отвечу, но на сколько я могу представить - он вполне может хранится упорядоченно ;)

Answer (score 1):

Поиск по индексу может осуществляться как по всем колонкам, так и по части из них,но не всегда, пример:
Например есть индекс по полям A, B, C

1. Запрос c where a=10, b= 20   - будет использовать индекс.
2. Запрос c where a=10   - будет использовать индекс.
3. Запрос c where b= 20   - НЕ будет использовать индекс.
4. Запрос c where a=10, с= 30   - будет использовать индекс но только по полю а.
5. Запрос c where b= 20, с=30   - НЕ будет использовать индекс.

Comment: В 3 и 5 варианте Oracle (да и не только) может использовать индекс.

Comment: а почему в 4 варианте по С не будет??

Comment: потому что как??? по с порядок только внутри каждого b условно говоря. что бы найти все с=30, надо просканить ВСЕ блоки  со всеми B !

Answer (score 0):

Если в составном индексе 1,2,3 колонка используется. А поиск идет по значениям 1 и 3, то, как показывает explain analyze, индекс будет использован только в самом начале - при фильтрации по 1 колонке.
Для остальных параметров (3 колонка) будет тупо перебор или нечто подобное, но безусловно медленней.

Есть специфика в зависимости от конкретной СУБД, но в целом составной ключ - экономит нам время на вводе данных, т.к. по сути генерирует один индекс из 3 полей (в моем примере), но искать нужно тогда либо по всем трем либо 1 и 2 или 1 полю.

Можно положить 3 индекса, по каждому полю отдельно, но при всатвке или апдейте будет пересчитываться сразу 3 индекса. 

В общем, если вставляем мало или редко чем ищем - то лучше 3 отдельных.